# Android Get the Background Ressource of an ImageButton

Tags: java, android, image, background, imagebutton

I need to get the background ressource of some ImageButton, to re-use it later, for set the background i use setBackgroundResource. I don't find any method to get the backgroundressource.

```
private void AddImage(int img){
    ImageButton imgact1 = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.imgact1);
    ImageButton imgact2 = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.imgact2);
    ImageButton imgact3 = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.imgact3);
    imgact3.setBackgroundResource(img);
}
```

Thanks for your help .

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageButton.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As for any `View`, you should use `getBackground()`, which returns a `Drawable`.

Comment: @Da-monk, You're welcome. Please don't forget to accept the answer in case you've found it helpful.

Comment: And how do I store that value in a string? What if the image is defined in `android:src` could I do the same? Thanks! PS: I have upvoted

Comment: This is because I am trying to compare values. EX: If the image is `red circle` then do this, if the image is `blue circle` then do this

Comment: I've tried   `if(buttonBackground.equals(@drawable/mydrawable))` but it doesn't work. That is where `Drawable buttonBackground = myButton.getBackground();`